Why is random sampling with ordinary and compiled code so different?
Consider the following code:
function[x_] = -0.2135096237485963` + 
   0.5230330267652104` Power[
    27.95584680618265` x + 
     Sqrt[(27.95584680618265` x - 9.569316101220256`)^2 + 
      42.46540146917953`] - 9.569316101220256`, (3)^-1] - 
   1.8247674462728896`/Power[
   27.95584680618265` x + 
    Sqrt[(27.95584680618265` x - 9.569316101220256`)^2 + 
     42.46540146917953`] - 9.569316101220256`, (3)^-1];
randvalscomp = 
  Hold@Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, 
      ArcCos[function[RandomReal[{0, 1}, n]]], 
      CompilationTarget -> "C"] /. DownValues@function // 
   ReleaseHold;

Now, let us generate 100 random numbers using uncompiled code and compiled code:
randvals1 = ArcCos[function[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 100]]];
randvals2 = randvalscomp[100];

By its structure (the way I have obtained it), function may only return the values between -1 and 1, so ArcCos must be real. While randvals1 contains only real numbers, randvals2 sometimes returns an arbitrarily large imaginary part. It does not look like a machine precision error: say, ArcCos[-1.00001] returns a vanishingly small imaginary part plus a real part - either Pi, while I may get arbitrary combinations:
Select[randvals2,Im[#]!=0&]


{1.24622 -1.19564 I,2.43982 -0.7189 I,2.36874 -0.814092 I,1.1946
-1.06941 I,2.4617 -0.514546 I,1.22451 -1.21208 I}

What may be the reason for this and how to fix it?
P.S. function may be obtained as
function1[u_,sin_]=(1/(1+8 sin^2-4 sin))(-((8 Power[2, (3)^-1] (1-2 sin)^2 sin^2)/Power[u+512 u sin^6-768 u sin^5+576 u sin^4-256 u sin^3+72 u sin^2+Sqrt[(u+256 (2 u-1) sin^6-192 (4 u-1) sin^5+48 (12 u-1) sin^4-256 u sin^3+72 u sin^2-12 u sin)^2+256 (1-2 sin)^6 sin^6]-12 u sin-256 sin^6+192 sin^5-48 sin^4, (3)^-1])+2^(2/3) Power[u+512 u sin^6-768 u sin^5+576 u sin^4-256 u sin^3+72 u sin^2+Sqrt[(u+256 (2 u-1) sin^6-192 (4 u-1) sin^5+48 (12 u-1) sin^4-256 u sin^3+72 u sin^2-12 u sin)^2+256 (1-2 sin)^6 sin^6]-12 u sin-256 sin^6+192 sin^5-48 sin^4, (3)^-1]-1+4 sin)

by replacing sin with 0.223: function[x_]=function1[x,0.223].

Don't you get a warning message when running randwalscomp? CompiledFunction::cfne: Numerical error encountered; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation.

@Domen : yes, but this is because I get complex numbers when using function. But why I am getting them? Without the compilation, the code works properly.

Your hackery way of injection function definitions into Compile is the root of your troubles. Observe the output of the following code:
Hold@compile[{{n, _Integer}}, function[randomReal[{0, 1}, n]]] /. 
 DownValues@function // ReleaseHold

You will see that randomReal is inserted at every appearance of x in function, which is of course a non-sense, because it should be "the same" x every time. You can also see this by looking at the output of CompiledFunctionTools`CompilePrint[randvalscomp] and seeing multiple occurences of RandomReals.
A solution is trivial: Sample random points only once before applying function.
randvalscomp = Hold@Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, 
 Module[{xs = RandomReal[{0, 1}, n]}, ArcCos[function[xs]]], 
 CompilationTarget -> "C"] /. DownValues@function // ReleaseHold;

